# using assembly in Turbo pascal: line too long

Tags: assembly, turbo-pascal

I have this line of code:

```
asm
...

    jmp @jmp_data
        @s1: dw $1120,$1120,$1120,$4420,$0020,$0020,$0020,$1120,$1120,$1120,$4420,$0020,$0020,$0020,$1120,$1120,$1120,$4420,$0020,$0020,$0020,$1120,$1120,$1120,$4420,$0020,$0020,$0020;
        @jmp_data:
...
end:
```

But turbo Pacal gives error 11: Line too long.

so i tried to do this:

```
jmp @jmp_data
@s1: dw $1120,$1120,$1120,$4420,$0020,$0020,$0020,$1120,$1120,$1120,$4420,$0020,
$0020,$0020,$1120,$1120,$1120,$4420,$0020,$0020,$0020,$1120,$1120,$1120,$4420,$0020,$0020,$0020;
@jmp_data:
```

But gives Syntax error.

I searched in Google about this, but i found nothing.

So, how can write this code in Turbo pascal? It's have to be some way.

Thank...

Comment: Just repeat the `dw` directive for the next lines too.

Comment: @Jester Yeah lol, I just realized, thank !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use several `dw` directives:

```
    @s1: dw $1120,$1120,$1120,$4420,$0020,$0020,$0020,$1120
         dw $1120,$1120,$4420,$0020,$0020,$0020,$1120,$1120
         dw $1120,$4420,$0020,$0020,$0020,$1120,$1120,$1120
         dw $4420,$0020,$0020,$0020
```